# How to run Matomo behind Traefik with sub path?

Tags: routes, docker-compose, traefik, bitnami, matomo

I'm setting up a docker-compose environment with Traefik (v1.7.16) as reverse proxy and want to include Matomo. I use the Bitnami images for Matomo and the backup database (MariaDB); both `latest`. The setup is similar to [Bitnami's example compose file](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-matomo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

I followed the instructions provided and everything works fine, except the routing with Traefik. E.g. I can run Matomo at `localhost:<exposedPort>` but not at `localhost/matomo`, so sub paths are not working.

What I did so far: As explained in the [Matomo FAQ](https://matomo.org/faq/how-to-install/faq_98/) I set the env variable `MATOMO_ENABLE_PROXY_URI_HEADER=yes` to set `proxy_uri_header = 1` in the `config.ini.php` (this works). Then I set the traefik labels for the Matomo service:

```
labels:
  - 'traefik.backend=matomo'
  - 'traefik.docker.network=proxy_traefik'
  - 'traefik.enable=true'
  - 'traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true'
  - 'traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=31536000'
  - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost; PathPrefixStrip:/matomo;'
  - 'traefik.frontend.headers.customRequestHeaders=X-Forwarded-Uri:localhost/matomo'
  - 'traefik.frontend.headers.hostsProxyHeaders=X-Forwarded-Uri'
  - 'traefik.port=80'
```

As a result i can load the page `localhost/matomo` but all internal URLs (like image and script URLs) refer to `localhost` only and doesn't include the path `/matomo`.

Is there something I missed setting up Traefik and Matomo?

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled with this myself the past week or so, and finally got it resolved.
As with OP, I'm still using traefik v1.7, and just discovered Matomo, and wanted to hook it up to a gitea container I setup for myself.

My traefik frontend rule label looks like this:

```
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: 'HostRegexp: ${DOMAIN_NAME}, {subdomain:[a-z]+}${DOMAIN_NAME}; PathPrefixStrip:/matomo/'
```

This is a special case, as I wanted matomo to always be on any hostname I use, as long as I add the /matomo/ to the URL.

A simpler version of this would be:

```
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: 'Host: ${DOMAIN_NAME}; PathPrefixStrip:/matomo/'
```

You can define DOMAIN_NAME in an .env file, or just replace with `localhost` to match your example.

What made the change for me was the last slash, without it accessing matomo would fail.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by looking at your description and the config snippets here, you want a **PathPrefix-Rule** here and not a **PathPrefixStrip-Rule**. That way, the internal URLs should get added after localhost/matomo, since matomo (your **prefix**) doesn't get **stripped** before being reverse-proxied to the backend.